# Cómo guardar multiples instancias de Formset creadas dinámicamente?

Tags: django

Estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto en Django pero he llegado a un punto en el que no puedo avanzar. Tengo un formulario CreateView de un modelo Padre (Entrada) el cual tiene diversas instancias de un formset hijo, BalaMateriasPrimeras. Mediante Javascript, puedo crear multiples instancias de BalaMateriasPrimeras, pero sólo puedo guardar el número de Formsets que tenga especificado en el extra=x del forms.py. Es decir:

-Si del hijo tengo extra=3, puedo crear mas, pero no se guardan. Si creo justo 3, si.

-Si del hijo tengo extra=1, puedo crear mas, pero no se guardan. Si creo justo 1, si.

No sé que puede fallar y estoy un poco desesperado después de un par de dias (con sus 8 horas) buscando qué pasa. Dejo el código relevante a mi duda:

**forms.py**

```
class EntradaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entrada
        exclude = ()


class BalaMateriesPrimeresForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BalaMateriesPrimeres
        fields = ['quilos', 'material', 'cost_unitari']

BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Entrada, BalaMateriesPrimeres, form=BalaMateriesPrimeresForm, can_delete=True, extra=1)
```

**views.py**

```
class EntradaCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Entrada
    fields = ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(EntradaCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['bala_form'] = BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet(self.request.POST)
            data['materials'] = Material.objects.all()
        else:
            data['bala_form'] = BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet()
            data['materials'] = Material.objects.all()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):

        context = self.get_context_data()
        bala_form = context['bala_form']
        print(bala_form)

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if bala_form.is_valid():
                bala_form.instance = self.object
                bala_form.num_entrada = self.object.id
                bala_form.save()
        return super(EntradaCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**plantilla.html**

```
  [....]
  <!-- Nested forms with desired number of boxes -->
  <div id="nested_forms_0">
    <div class="row" id="box_0">
      {% for bala in bala_form %}
      <div class="col-3 text-center">
        <h5>Bala #1: </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center">
        {{ bala.quilos }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center" >
        {{ bala.material }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 text-center" >
        {{ bala.cost_unitari }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center">
        <button type="button" id='remove_box_0' class="btn btn-danger">Elimina Bala</button>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div> <!-- /Bala form -->
  </div>  <!-- /Nested forms -->
</div>  <!-- /Form -->
<p>
  {{ bala_form.management_form }}
  <input id="crear" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block btn-option btn-form" type="submit" value="Crear" />
</p>
```

Como ya dije, tan solo puedo guardar el numero que tenga en *extra*. Debo de tener algun error pequeño que haga que no pueda guardarlo, pero no lo veo. A ver si alguien me puede tirar una mano.

Comment: Diría que revises que llega al servidor en esta variable cuando haces el POST `TOTAL_FORMS ` porque ese extra, solo sirve para añadirte la cantidad de formularios extra inicial, pero si no modificas la variable que te digo, entonces el solo va a validar el numero que contenga en `extra` solo asegurate de ver que está llegando al servidor con esa variable y luego yo te ayudo a corregir el error

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios puntos que se pueden mejorar, te dejo mi solución para tu problema:

```
from django import forms

class EntradaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entrada
        fields = '__all__'


class BalaMateriesPrimeresForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BalaMateriesPrimeres
        fields = ['quilos', 'material', 'cost_unitari']

BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Entrada,
    BalaMateriesPrimeres,
    form=BalaMateriesPrimeresForm,
    can_delete=True,
    extra=1
)

class EntradaCreateUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Entrada
    form_class = EntradaForm
    formset_class = BalaMateriesPrimeresFormSet

    def get_formset(self):
        return self.formset_class(**self.get_formset_kwargs())

    def get_formset_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['instance'] = self.object
        return kwargs

    def get_object(self):
        self.creating = 'pk' not in self.kwargs
        if self.creating:
            return None # Success
        else:
            obj = super().get_object()
            return obj

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        formset = self.get_formset()
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, formset)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, formset)

    def form_valid(self, form, formset):
        self.object = form.save()
        # Puede iterar cada formulario del formset y hacer lo que quieras
        for fmset in formset:
            fmset.save()
        # Puedes guardar el formulario si no necesita realizar ningún cambio
        # formset.save()
        return super(EntradaCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form, formset):
        # form y formset ya están en modo "bounded" y traen toda la información
        # y errores previamente pasados.
        return self.render_to_response(**self.get_context_data({'form': form, 'formset': formset}))
```

Note que EntradaCreateUpdateView() la puedes usar para crear y editar, el problema basicamente es el mal manejo de los formularios.
Ahora solo debes apuntar dos urlconf a la misma vista una con el argumento "pk" y el otro sin el.

Comment: Acabo de probar el código y tiene sentido, pero llega a un punto en el que me da el siguiente error:

    **TypeError at /entrades/create
    super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**

El error me refiere a línea donde capturamos los kwargs en el get_formset_kwargs. He cambiado *CreateView* por *EntradaCreateUpdateView* sin resultado. Con el Django Debug Toolbar veo que sí tengo acceso a los datos como se puede ver en el POST:

https://imgur.com/a/ZlxR6Z5 peró aún así me sigue dando error.

Comment: Vale, he podido solucionarlo con un

Comment: Hola @DavidMM ¿como lo solucionaste?